# Is a serialization anomaly only possible with SUM/COUNT?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, isolation-level

I have read [Deeply understand Isolation levels and Read phenomena in MySQL & PostgreSQL](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/understand-isolation-levels-read-phenomena-in-mysql-postgres-c2e#serialization-anomaly-in-postgres) and especially the part "Serialization anomaly in Postgres". I think I've understood the problem described there, but I have a hard time to judge when it could happen in my application.

Is it only possible with aggregate functions like SUM/COUNT to get a serialization anomaly in Postgres? If not, what else do I have to watch out for?

Comment: Well, you can only get a serialization anomaly if you have concurrent and conflicting transactions. But the situation described there can be avoided using the `serializable` isolation level.

Comment: `serializable` is pretty costly. I want to avoid it, if it's not necessary. Hence I try to figure out if it is necessary with my application / my types of queries.

Comment: So the question in other words is: What are *conflicting transactions*? What do I have to look out for?

Comment: No, serializable is not "pretty costly". It is indeed somewhat slower than `read committed` but not substantially. The negative impact depends mostly on how many transactions are aborted due to a serialization error.

Comment: The main cost involved is in making sure your app or users stand ready to retry transactions when they get served serialization errors.

Comment: "The main cost involved is in making sure your app or users stand ready to retry transactions" - that would be all the time if the whole app runs under `serializable`, right? So you @jjanes directly contradict @a_horse_with_no_name, do you?

Comment: There are different ways of defining and measuring cost.

Comment: Some good follow-on reading: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/a-critique-of-ansi-sql-isolation-levels/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's an example attributed to Jim Gray.

There are two rows in the database. One has the value "white" and the other "black". Transaction T1 updates all white to black, T2 all black to white.

```
update table
set value = 'black'
where value = 'white'
```

Each transaction reads exactly one row and writes that same row. The working sets of each transaction are completely disjoint. Under pessimistic concurrency control there need not be any lock conflict. Under optimistic there is no write-set conflict.

To be serialisable we must end up with all values white or all black. If run concurrently at lower isolation, however, we can end with the rows swapping values instead.

Comment: I'm very surprised by your answer. Isn't it already covered by "Read uncommitted" in postgres? This looks to me like a `dirty read`: "A transaction reads data written by a concurrent uncommitted transaction."

Comment: It is the nature of anomalies to be surprising.

Comment: @MartinThoma neither transaction reads data from the other. One transaction reads all rows with 'white', the other all rows with 'black'.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes! I needed the edit "the working sets of each transaction are completely disjoint." to realize why this is not as simple as I assumed 